HEROKU (Dockerfile that does not exist)
tried hosting my django website on Heroku, but keeps getting dockfile does not exist which is from the heroku.yml file
Waiting on build...
Waiting on build... (elapsed: 6s)
Waiting on build... (elapsed: 9s)
=== Fetching app code
=!= There were problems parsing your heroku.yml. We've detected the following issues:
build.docker.web references a Dockerfile that does not exist
below is a screenshoot of my vscode explorer and heroku.yml fileVScode Screenshot
